# User Class: обработка ошибок, исключений

Tags: ооп, php, users, классы

Всем привет, решил написать класс для работы с пользователеми. 
В конструкторе, я решил делать проверку, авторизован ли пользователь, проверить сессии и куки. Далее идёт метод в котором дёргаем инфу из бд, также сначала проверяем, есть ли такой пользователь в бд. Хотелось бы узнать, возможно вы уже увидели метод ерроров, вот, как лучше всё это организовать, хотелось бы узнать, стоит ли вообще отводить на ерроры отдельный метод, и как лучше делать исключения в ООП? or die я так понимаю это неправильно) Смотрю в строну эксепшон, прошу помочь) Код:

```
class User {

public $id = null;
public $login = null;
public $email = null;
private $hash = null;
private $error;

/*
* Mетоды
*/

public function __construct(){
    if ($_SESSION['hash'] && $_SESSION['login']){

        $this->hash = $_SESSION['hash'];
        $this->login = $_SESSION['login'];

    }else if ($_COOKIE['hash'] && $_COOKIE['login']){

        $this->hash = $_COOKIE['hash'];
        $this->login = $_COOKIE['login'];

    }
public getError(){
    if ($this->error){return $this->error;}
}
public function UserInfo(){
    if ($this->hash && $this->login)
    {
        // Предположим, что пользователь авторизован
        // Проверим есть ли такой пользователь в БД

        $sql = $db->("SELECT * FROM users WHERE hash = ? AND login = ?");
        $sql->bind_param('??',$hash,$login);

        $hash = $this->hash;
        $login = $this->login;

        $sql->execute() or die("Предупреждение о неудачном запросе");
        $row = $sql->get_result();
        if ($row->num_rows == 1){

            /*
            * Тут дёргаем инфу
            */

        } else {
            // Clear DATA
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Так вы цель какую преследуете?

У нас, например, PHP выполняет вспомогательную функцию, типа сервисов что-то. Если возникла ошибка в методе - кидаем exception, который ловится на самом верхнем уровне (в PHP), затем оборачивается в приемлемый для клиента вид и возвращается ему (клиенту).

Таким образом клиент знает - был ли обработан запрос или во время выполнения возникла ошибка.

Если у вас клиент (читай страница в браузере) самодостаточна и PHP используется вспомогательно, то вам подойдет этот способ.

Если же html и php переплетен - то ошибки надо как-то собирать, а затем выводить...

Answer (score 2):

Тема обработки исключений - одна из самых сложных для пользователей РНР. В 4 версии их не было, а все видеоуроки сделаны именно под неё. Поэтому столкнувшись с исключениями, каждый начинает изобретать кто во что горазд. Отсюда рождается множество мифов и суеверий, главное из которых - "Помещаем код, который может вызвать исключение, в блок try{}catch(){}".

Вообще, тема работы с исключениями слишком обширна для того, чтобы описать ее всю в одном посте. Но вот задача обработки ошибок БД, которая интересовала автора вопроса два года назад, как раз довольно легко алгоритмизируется.

Судя по коду, в качестве драйвера БД используется mysqli. В это случае **никакого специального кода для обработки ошибок БД писать не нужно.** Вместо этого перед кодом соединения пишем единственную строчку:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

поле этого любая ошибка БД породит исключение РНР. Всё. **Больше ничего делать не надо.** По двум причинам.

1. РНР всё сделает как надо сам.
2. Пытаясь что-то улучшить, пользователь скорее всего сделает только хуже.

Поэтому опять же, ограничимся настройками РНР.

- Боевой сервер, который посещают пользователи, настраиваем так:

  ```
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors',0);
  ini_set('log_errors',1);
  ```
- а сервер разработчика - так:

  ```
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors',1);
  ```

В итоге любая ошибка базы данных будет трансформирована в исключение, а неотловленное исключение - это фатальная ошибка РНР. А с обработкой ошибок РНР отлично справляется сам, в соответствии с вышеприведенными директивами:

- На сервере разработчика ошибка будет сразу показана на экране, чтобы ее тут же можно было было увидеть и исправить
- На боевом сервере ошибка пойдет в лог, чтобы программист смог ее увидеть и исправить. А пользователю браузер покажет стандартное сообщение о том, что на сервере произошла ошибка.

Ничего лучше и желать нельзя!

Ну разве только если мы захотим, чтобы браузер показывал не свою собственную, а нашу страницу об ошибке, то для этого просто настроим веб-сервер, чтобы он, получив от РНР заголовок, говорящий об ошибке, отдавал пользователю определенную страницу.

Отдельно следует отметить обрабатываемые исключения. Но это совсем отдельная тема. Если коротко, то в случае, когда у нас есть определенный сценарий обработки ошибки, то мы заключаем проблемную строку в try..catch. Скажем, мы хотим отлавливать ошибку с дублирующимся именем пользователя. В таком случае заключаем строку исполнения запроса в try..catch, ловим ошибку, **и проверяем, та ли это ошибка, которая нам нужна.** Если та - то действуем по своему сценарию. Если нет - кидаем исключение снова.

Answer (score -1):

Конечно die быть не должно. Должен быть try-cacth там, где ожидается exception. Функция должна просто вернуть false или сообщение об ошибке, зависит от задумки.

Ещё непонятны эти танцы:

```
$hash = $this->hash;
$login = $this->login;
```

У вас уже есть эти данные в свойствах экземпляра класса, зачем их пихать в локальные переменные?

Answer (score -1):

Как это делают другие:

1. Пишем отдельный класс для обработки ошибок ErrorHandler
2. Помещаем код, который может вызвать исключение в блок try{}catch(){}
3. Вызываем в необходимых местах генерацию исключений:

   ```
   if(!$sql->execute()){
       throw new \Exсeption("Произошла ошибка. Программа не может выполнить метод execute....");
   }
   ```
4. Внутри блока catch говорим, что обрабатывать наше исключение будет метод написанного класса.